# Hugo code fences output two tags, pre and code

Tags: hugo

Is there any way to tweak how Hugo output codefences?

if I have some markdown like so:

````
 ```csharp
    //some code
 ```
````

It will be generated as:

```
<pre class="language-csharp">
<code class="language-csharp">
//some code
```

Can I somehow change the pre+code output?
I'm trying to integrate Mermaid.js into my site and this fails due to having the two tags.
If it manages to hook onto the code tag, the Mermaid output is just shown as `code` inside the `pre`

And if it hooks onto the `pre`, then the inner text is wrong and cant be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stuck on this issue, here is how I ended up solving it.

In the template for our pages, we take the content of the markdown file.
Then find-replace `language-mermaid` with just `mermaid`.
This prevents collision with other libraries like Prism.JS.
And it allows Mermaid.JS to correctly find the proper tag and class to hook into.

```
<div>
{{ $content := .Content }}
//other replace hacks ....
//...
{{ $content = replace $content "language-mermaid" "mermaid" }}

{{ safeHTML $content}}
```

This results in generated files containing the following output.

```
<pre>
<code class="mermaid">
...
```

Ugly hack, but works. so that is good enough for us right now.

Answer (score 0):

So far, 6th March 2022, **it is not possible**. According to the [official documentation](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup#markdown-render-hooks), only images, links, and headings are adjustable in this way.

**However**, you should be able to create your own [shortcode](https://gohugo.io/templates/shortcode-templates/) and implement it in a way that will provide you the features you want to get and use.